# SSL Verification blocking API query for no good reason

Tags: python, security, ssl

I'm working on a script that has to extract some data from ConnectWise and I'm running into what I feel is an exceptionally silly problem. At the moment, all my script does is query ConnectWise for company info as described [here](https://developer.connectwise.com/Best_Practices/PSA_Cloud_URL_Formatting?mt-learningpath=manage) (I think you may not be able to log into that page without a Connectwise Developer account, but it's essentially just a URL to get basic company information so you can format your URL correctly for future queries). When I run this simple request, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 467, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  ...
    ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1006)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
  ...
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='example.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /path (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1006)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path\to\your\script.py", line 26, in <module>
    main()
  ...
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='example.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /path (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1006)')))
```

I could simply disable SSL and do my thing, but that's bad practice for a good reason. I'm running Python 3.11.7 in a virtual environment. I've already tried upgrading certifi and that had no effect - it was already fully upgraded. We can do this from my boss's computer without any trouble and I'm able to do the same query from Postman without an issue so my virtualenv feels like a likely culprit. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please include your code.  What system are you running this script on?

Comment: postman doesn't check SSL/TLS certificates so that doesn't prove anything. Are you sure your connection isn't being intercepted? The real server for developer.connectwise.com serves a chain that does NOT contain a self-signed cert -- and so does the one for example.com. If you have or get OpenSSL, do `openssl s_client -connect $host:443 -showcerts <NUL:` (`/dev/null` on Unix; add `-servername $host` if below 1.1.1 which is unlikely) and look at the certs to see if they form the chain to the real CA used by the server (Starfield or DigiCert respectively) or something else.

Comment: This is now giving a different error so I'm going to drop it for now. Thanks!